# Linux. Выполнение команд из .bashrc. Ошибка создания папки. Permission denied

Tags: linux

В файле `.bashrc` прописано создание папок виртуальной среды:

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/var/www/_virtualenvs/django_env/bin/python3
export WORKON_HOME=/var/www/_virtualenvs/
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

По команде `admin@gp16:~$ source ~/.bashrc` выдается ошибка:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/www’: Permission denied
```

при этом пользователь `admin` состоит в группе `sudoers`.

Кроме того все команды создания проекта Django, например,

`(django_env) admin@gp16:/var/www/sites/django$ django-admin.py startproject project_name` заканчиваются этой же ошибкой:

```
CommandError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/sites/django/
```

Где можно проверить и поправить настройки доступа?

> **PS:** Ошибки возникают в `ubuntu 20.04`.
> В **`ubuntu 20.10` - всё проходит нормально!**

Comment: Простите, а зачем вообще их создавать через .bashrc?

Comment: Чтобы одновременно внести их в пременные среды окружения. Вручную соданные папки не меняют результаты создания окружения - та же ошибка доступа. Это общая проблема для команд создания проекта Django.

Comment: Всё равно непонятна задача. Создать папки можно один раз вручную, и потом пользоваться заранее созданными папками. Зачем создавать их каджый раз через .bashrc?

Comment: Если у вас нет доступа к нужным вам папкам — значит выдайте его себе командами chown/chmod, django и bashrc тут ни при чём

Comment: Сайт переезжает на другой хост и я настраваю систему по это дело. Содал папки вручную и явилось неоданностью отсутствие прав на них при создании проекта. Проверяю права тех же папок на старом хосте и они совпадают. Откуда взялась ошибка доступа не могу вычислить, т.к. цепь настроек была  небольшая...

Comment: Без подробной информации могу только предположить, что невнимательно проверяете. (Не по теме вопроса отмечу, что по-хорошему настройка системы должна выполняться как минимум по заранее написанной инструкции после тщательной репетиции всех действий в виртуальной машине, а как максимум — полностью автоматизированно например через Ansible-плейбук)

Comment: Именно так я и настраиваю - по многократно проверенному мануалу. А в этот раз что пошло не так!

Comment: Папки проверил по свей цепочке.. Может быть более общая настройка влияет, о которой я не знаю. Уже пол интернета облазил в поисках...

Comment: Возможно стоит перед  mkdir добавить sudo ?